# value foo in class MyJavaClass of type java.lang.String has incompatible type mixing in Java class and Scala trait

Tags: java, scala, traits

I have a Scala trait

```
trait MyTrait{  
  val foo: String
  def bar = foo
}
```

and a Java class that provides foo

```
public class MyJavaClass {
    public final String foo = "hello";
}
```

Now I try to mix them

```
class MyScalaClass extends MyJavaClass with MyTrait { 
}
```

it won't compile

```
overriding value foo in trait MyTrait of type String;  value foo in class MyJavaClass of type java.lang.String has incompatible type.
```

I've tried every combination of vals, vars and defs that seem plausible, but can't find any way of compiling this configuration.

How can I provide a trait's val with a Java class?

Comment: Can you change the Java class?

Comment: I _could_ change the Java class - providing a getter, but I'd rather understand why fields don't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is due to the fact that Scala generates getters and setters for "public" variables - the variables themselves are always private, but `scalac` makes them look as if they're publically accessible.

In other words, I believe your `val foo: String` declaration in the trait is actually equivalent to:

```
// def foo_=(s: String)  // setter - would apply to var declarations
def foo: String      // getter
```

so you'd need to provide a Java class that implemented the `foo` *method*, rather than exposing a public *variable*.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense, so I guess that the answer is that I can't use a Java field to provide a val.

Comment: @Duncan I believe that's an accurate assessment, yes.